# Modules in Morita Equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, equivalence-relations

In *Method of Homological Algebra* by *Gelfand* and *Manin* (Exercise 2.2.3).

[image]

How are $\mathrm{Hom}_A(P,X)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_B(P^*,Y)\,$  regarded as a $B$-module and $A$-module respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,X)$ is a $B=\operatorname{End}_AP$-module via $f\cdot b:= f\circ b$ whild $\operatorname{Hom}_B(P^*,Y)$ is an $A$-module via $(f\cdot a)(p):=f(ap)$, where for $ap$ you use the left $A$-module structure on $P^*$. I leave it as an exercise for you to check that this defines right module structures.